# Fluxxor - how to dispatch an action in response to another?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I feel like subtitling this question "Does Fluxxor want my application to work?". No doubt however I have not grasped how to co-operate with Fluxxor...

The error is:

Cannot dispatch an action ('NEXT_AJAX_REQUEST_IS_ABOUT_TO_BE_MADE') while another action ('FIRST_AJAX_REQUEST_IS_RETURNED') is being dispatched

Component A is the owner of Component B

Component A calls an action creator in its componentWillReceiveProps. This action creator makes an AJAX request. If successful we dispatch FIRST_AJAX_REQUEST_IS_RETURNED with some data into a store. The store updates. It emits change. Component A is listening for this change. Component A updates its state. Component A re-renders passing this state as props to Component B. Component B in its componentWillReceiveProps calls an action creator to make a second AJAX request based on the data it now has. Before the actual AJAX request is made the action creator dispatches NEXT_AJAX_REQUEST_IS_ABOUT_TO_BE_MADE - in order to put a store into a certain state.

I get the message about dispatching one action while another is in progress it seems because Fluxxor does not consider the first action complete  - even though I cannot have made the second until the AJAX request was completed and I have the data. The issue seems to be calling the second action from the componentWillReceiveProps method of a child component in response to changes in the owner component's state arising from the first action.

So. I tried moving the second action to the success 'callback' in the first store. I still get the same message. Even if this was the right thing to do...

The second action depends on data contained in the first action. I cannot merge these two into one single request/action and then update 2 stores using waitFor.

Answer (score 0):

http://fluxxor.com/guides/react.html#batched-updates

This fixed it.

However I do not understand why and would really appreciate an explanation if anyone has it.

I think that the effect is that Component A will not re-render until state changes arising from getStateFromFlux have fully completed. So that when Component B calls its action creator we are now fully done with the first action.

Is this approximately correct?